# Extracting a ball from an urn, introducing it into the second. Expected value=?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

We have two urns, the first with 6 white balls and 7 black balls and the second with 10
white balls and 5 black balls.

We extract a ball from the first urn and introduce it into the second one, then we extract from the second urn 5 balls, without reintroducing them back after each extraction.

If X is the nr. of white balls of the 5 extracted from the second urn, what is the expected value of X?

My line of thought was that I could find the probability of extracting a white ball from the first urn, then somehow adding it to the nr of white balls in the second urn, however i am at a loss of what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a $\frac{6}{13}$ chance of drawing a white ball from the first urn which would give the second urn $11$ white and $5$ black balls. You have a $\frac{7}{13}$ chance of drawing a black ball from the first urn which would give the second urn $10$ white and $6$ black balls.
$$
\overbrace{\frac{6}{13}\underbrace{\frac{11}{16}5}_{\substack{\text{expected}\\\text{number}\\\text{of white}\\\text{drawn}}}}^{\text{white drawn from first urn}}+\overbrace{\frac{7}{13}\underbrace{\frac{10}{16}5}_{\substack{\text{expected}\\\text{number}\\\text{of white}\\\text{drawn}}}}^{\text{black drawn from first urn}}
$$

Comment: Thank you! it is very clear now